# Is there a way to remove object in the datalayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-ads-api

Is there a way to remove object in the datalayer? As seen on the picture, there are two 'google_tag_params' object. I just need one. First push is onload then the second push on dataLayer in a js call. I need to remove the pushed one first before pushing the second so there is no duplicate 'google_tag_params' in the data layer

[image]

```
dataLayer.push(
            {   "google_tag_params":google_tag_params, 
                "ecomm_prodid":document.getElementById('prodid').value,
                "ecomm_pagetype": document.getElementById('pageType').value,
                "ecomm_totalvalue": price.toFixed(2),
            });
```

Comment: You can just do `dataLayer.pop`. At the end its just an array on `window`.

Comment: That will remove the last object. Not the Object I need to be removed.

Comment: Point is, its just another array. You can loop over it and remove it using `array.splice()`

Comment: `dataLayer = dataLayer.filter(x=>!x.google_tag_params)`

Comment: dataLayer = dataLayer.filter(x=>!x.google_tag_params) <-- this one worked. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Array [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
//es6
dataLayer = dataLayer.filter(x=>!x.google_tag_params);//removes any object
            // which has a key google_tag_params, guessing that its value won't be falsy
 // better use x => !(google_tag_params in x)
dataLayer.push(newGoogleTagParam);

//es5
dataLayer = dataLayer.filter(function (x) {
  return !x.google_tag_params;
});
dataLayer.push(newGoogleParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove data from the data layer by [setting](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/datalayer#set) the key to an undefined value. Example:

```
window.dataLayer.push(function(){ this.set('google_tag_params') });
```

Note, in your scenario `google_tag_params` *might* be pushed twice for good reason.  And as long as both objects contain all relevant data for their respective tags, each tag will fire with the relevant data.  But if you want to be absolutely sure the second isn't inheriting data from the first, you can run the above code in between pushes to clear that key's data.